# What is wrong with my min function?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function that returns the minimum number from an array:

Function definition:

```
pub fn min(input_array: &[i32]) -> &i32 {
    let x = input_array.iter().min().unwrap();
    x
}
```

Test:

```
fn test_min() {
    let input_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    assert_eq!(1, functional::min(&input_array));
}
```

But when I run it I get the error:

```
    <std macros>:5:8: 5:33 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<&i32>` is not implemented for the type `_` [E0277]
<std macros>:5 if ! ( * left_val == * right_val ) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/functional.rs:104:5: 104:50 note: in this expansion of assert_eq! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:5:8: 5:33 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `gettingrusty`.
```

Comment: Check the type of `x` with `let _: () = x;`, most likely its type is `&i32` and I am sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Are you sure thats the error? `min` returns `Option<Self::Item>`... I assume you're unwrapping that and didn't include it in your snippet?

Comment: Sorry added the missing sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `min` is ok (assuming you want to return a `&i32`), the error is in the `assert`.
This is correct:

```
assert_eq!(&1, min(&input_array));
```

Comment: What does "&1" mean ?

Comment: @LowKianSeong It'a reference to the temporary value 1. Your `min` returns a reference, so you have to compare that with another reference. `&1` is a reference and it works, `1` alone is not a `&i32` is a `i32` so it doesn't compile.

Comment: Another possible fix is to not return a reference: change `-> &i32` to `-> i32` and the second `x` to `*x`.